# Laravel - Soft delete isn't taking effect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm having an issue with soft delete. I have a feature in my app where a user can star a followed property advert. They can also unstar a property advert.

This works fine. when they unstar it, the record is soft delete. The delete_at timestamp is updated.

However, if the user tries to star it again, I get a message saying that the property has already been liked/starred. So the soft delete is being ignored? Any ideas?

StarredPropertyModel

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class StarredProperty extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['property_id', 'user_id'];

    public function scopeStarredProperty($query, $propertyId, $userId)
    {
        return $query->where('property_id', $propertyId)->where('user_id', $userId)->first();
    }
}
```

StarredPropertyController

```
class StarredPropertyController extends Controller
{
    public function star(Property $property, User $user, Request $request)
    {     
        if(!$user->starredProperties()->starredProperty($property->id, $user->id))
        {
            return response()->json(StarredProperty::create(['property_id' => $property->id, 'user_id' => $user->id]));
        }

        return response()->json('You have already like this property');
    }

    public function unstar(Property $property, User $user, Request $request)
    {
        $starredProperty = $user->starredProperties()->starredProperty($property->id, $user->id);

        if($starredProperty->exists())
        {
            $starredProperty->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `->get()` at the end of the if that checks if starredProperty exists on the star function.
`$user->starredProperties()->starredProperty($property->id, $user->id)` returns a query, not a record. To get the record you still need to execute `get`, if there are no records then the value returned from `get` will be `null`.

Comment: StarredProperty is a queryscope on the model in my first block of code. The query returns a first() record.

Comment: You should not be doing that first on the scope, scopes should be returning query builder instances, check this answer: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/make-query-scope-only-return-one-object

Comment: Great thank you. So I should never use first or get on a scope?

Comment: No, scopes are just meant to be chained to form complex queries, once you have formed the query by chaining scopes on your controller you can call get or first to actually execute the query made by all scopes chained.